# Log4net hourly rollover but with datePattern of seconds

Tags: log4net

I'm trying to write a log which creates new file every hour, which can be done simply using the datePattern set to  **but** I need the datePattern (or at least the filename to consist of yyyyMMddHHmmss but still, rollover every 1 hour.

Obviously when I set  it gives the result but the rollover is every second.

I've search all over but couldn't find any answer.

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Log4net does not support this. You could copy the source code of the rolling file appender and implement this feature for yourself. As far as I can tell you cannot derive from the class and override the behavior since the date pattern is used in private methods.